# inserting objects onto ostreams

Tags: c++, std

I want to put a text description of a class instance onto an ostream, as in

```
ostream << myInstance;
```

I know how to declare an ostream inserter;

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream&, myClass&);
```

I want to be able to put different levels of detail to the ostream. I could do this if I could define two or more ostream inserters, or pass an extra argument to the inserter, or pass a method to the inserter, or perhaps call a method that returns a stringstream (can I do that?)

Has anyone solved this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add "flags" into the stream by actually encaspulating the stream itself.

```
struct Verbose {
  explicit Verbose(std::ostream* s = 0): _stream(s) {}
  std::ostream* _stream;
};

Verbose operator<<(std::ostream& out, Verbose) {
  return Verbose(&out);
}
```

And then, you define a new operator for verbose output:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(Verbose v, MyClass const& mc) {
  assert(v._stream);
  std::ostream& out = *v._stream;

  // ...
  return out;
}
```

Usage:

```
std::cout << Verbose() << myInstance << "\n";
```

You'll note that `Verbose` is not tied to the class, at all, and can be reused accross classes easily enough.

Note: if you want to, you could add an extra parameter to `Verbose` to actually control the level of verbosity directly there.

Comment: This is what I was looking for; simple and effective. The risk with this solution is that if your object doesn't know verbose, you'll get a compile error. A solution below lets you avoid that problem, but it wouldn't work if Verbose wanted to have multiple flags or other kinds of information.

Answer (score 2):

The standard solution is to define a custom manipulator, using flags or 
other formatting information stored in data provided by `ios::xalloc`.
Something like:

```
int
flagIndex()
{
    static int const theIndex = std::ostream::xalloc();
    return theIndex;
}

std::ostream&
verbose( std::ostream& stream )
{
    stream.iword( flagIndex() ) = 1;
    return stream;
}

std::ostream&
unverbose( std::ostream& stream )
{
    stream.iword( flagIndex() ) = 0;
    return stream;
}

std::ostream&
operator<<( std::ostream& dest, MyClass const& object )
{
    bool verbose = dest.iword( flagIndex() ) != 0;
    //  ...
    return dest;
}
```

You can then write things like:

```
std::cerr << verbose << myObject;
```

Comment: This is the standard answer. It's a pretty big effort to have to make. I was looking for something clever and simple.

Comment: Wow: I didn't this was so difficult either (never really dug into streams, they are too un-STL like for my taste).

Comment: @seattlecpp What's so difficult about it?  But if you don't like it, another frequent solution is to use a decorator; a `VerboseMyClass` which contains a pointer to a `MyClass`, but formats differently.  In most cases, I prefer the above.  And finally, although I don't like it, you can always hijack some of the existing flags: use the verbose format if `boolalpha` is set, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add extra parameters to `operator<<`, but you can easily define a custom printing function taking a *verbosity* parameter:

```
void dump(ostream& ostr, const myClass& obj, int verbosity = 1)
{
    if (verbosity > 2)
      ostr << "Very verbose!\n";
    if (verbosity > 1)
      ostr << "Verbose!\n";
    if (verbosity > 0)
      ostr << "Standard!\n";
    ostr << "Minimal.\n";
}
```

Usage:

```
dump(cout, myobj);     // Default
dump(cout, myobj, 0);  // Minimal
dump(cout, myobj, 1);  // Default
dump(cout, myobj, 2);  // Verbose
dump(cout, myobj, 3);  // Very verbose
```

You should also provide a stream operator forwarding to `dump()`, using the default verbosity:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& ostr, const myClass& obj)
{
    dump(ostr, obj);
    return ostr;
}
```

If you want to follow that way, it might be a good idea to declare an `enum` for the verbosity instead of using `int`s:

```
enum Verbosity
{
    MinimalOutput = 0,
    StandardOutput = 1,
    VerboseOutput = 2,
    DebugOutput = 3
};
```

Comment: Yes, of course I can do my own custom printing method, but I want something that works with ostreams and stringstreams, and lets me just insert a reference to the object.

Comment: @seattlecpp: A `stringstream` *is* an `ostream`, and you can "just insert" (?) a reference to the printing method.  Note that `operator<<` is just syntactic sugar, otherwise it is absolutely equivalent to a function.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to modify the formatting of your item would be to implement a manipulator. It will typically do little more than set some flag(s). Your inserter will then modify its behavior based on the state of the flag(s).